# Dialog create using singleton

Tags: c++, visual-c++, user-interface, mfc

I'm trying to create not modal dialog using singleton.

```
CMyDlg& CMyDlg::GetInstance()
{
    static CMyDlg myDlg;
    return myDlg;
}
```

then on some button press I call Create

```
CMyMain::OnSomeButtonPress()
{
    CMyDlg::GetInstance().Create( CMyDlg::IDD );
}
```

but problem is when I'm tryig to call Create twice it fails(something in wincore.cpp line 638)

What I'm doing wrong and why

```
CMyDlg::GetInstance().Create( CMyDlg::IDD );
```

can't be called twice?

Comment: When the dialog is created, it's created. You can't create the same thing twice, it would be like building the same house twice (no not build a *copy* of the same house, but build the exact same house twice).

Comment: Search "MFC modeless dialog" on google and you will find plenty of explanations and samples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CMyDlg` ultimately derives from `CWnd`, which wraps an `HWND` handle. `Create()` method goes from "this instance doesn't represent any physical window, `m_hWnd` is `NULL`" state to "this instance corresponds to a physical window, `m_hWnd` is a handle to that window" state. Naturally, `Create()` asserts first thing that `m_hWnd` is, indeed, `NULL`.

If you want two dialogs to show up on the screen at the same time, then you need two instances of `CMyDlg` to represent them; you can't use a singleton. If you don't want two dialogs, then why again are you calling `Create()` twice?

Comment: I don't want 2 dialogs at the same time.I assume that when I push Ok or Cancel my dialog is destroyed(but I don't know how properly destroy window) and than I can create window second time.

Comment: No, your dialog is not destroyed, unless you handle OK and Cancel button clicks and call `DestroyWindow` there.

Answer (score 0):

At the end I just use pointer to dialog.

```
CMyDlg* m_pDlg= NULL;
CMyDlg* CMyDlg::GetInstance()
{
    m_pDlg= new CMyDlg;
    m_pDlg->Create(CMyDlg::IDD);
    return m_pDlg;
}

void CMain::OnSomeButtonPress()
{
    CMyDlg::GetInstance();
}


void CMyDlg::OnBnClickedCancel()
{
    if(m_pDlg!= NULL)
        delete m_pDlg;
}
```